# Placeholder não identifica caracteres

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Eu estou com um problema com um placeholder e um a pagina de login,

```
<div class="group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Email, new { required = "required" } )  <span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
        <label >E-mail</label>

    </div>
```

Esse placeholder e email `<label>E-mail<label>` .Ele fica na Textarea aonde eu devo digitar o email, assim que eu clico e sobre e da espaço para digitar o email, o problema e que caso recarregue a pagina ou  erre a senha, ele volta e fica em cima do email que eu digitei deixando assim ilegível.

Eu estava querendo usar o angular , ng-show ou ng-dirty para ele identificar quando tem alguma coisa no input, mas tenho pouca experiencia em web, então queria pedir a ajuda de vocês .

Essa pagina não foi eu quem fez então eu apenas preciso arrumar este problema, eu s preciso que quando a pagina carregue ele identifique que tem algo escrito e tie o E-mail da textarea.

Se alguém puder me ajudar ou precisar de mais alguma informação eu ficarei grato.

PS.  Eu vi uma solução parecido com essa :

```
<div class="group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Email, new { required = "required", ng_model="email" } )  <span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
        <label  ng-show="email == 0">E-mail</label>

    </div>
```

Mas isso não está funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O placeholder somente para escrever o dentro do textbox, como vc está usando o textboxfor a propriedade email do seu objeto pojo não esta limpando tenta usar assim

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @placeholder = "E-mail" })
```

Comment: De certa forma isso resolve , o problema e que do jeito que tá atualmente o placeholder, no caso a label, ele faz uma animação de subir quando clica na textarea.  Mas como eu não conheço esse atributo eu não consigo mudar.

Comment: verifica o css do seu objeto <span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span> as classes que devem estar fazendo esse efeito